# Redux - Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to learn Redux (with conjunction with ReactJS) and when I try to add an article title, the app crashes and reads the following:

> Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

So I tried debugging my code by outputting it to the console and I do indeed get my ID and title, but when it comes to dispatching the `ADD_ARTICLE` action, it doesn't work.

Here is the specific code in question:

> Reducer

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
    articles: []
}

export default ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case ADD_ARTICLE:
            return [ ...state, action.article ] // Problem line
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

> Action Generator

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
import uuid from 'uuid'

export const addArticle = ( { title } = {} ) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_ARTICLE,
        // the payload
        article: {
            id: uuid(),
            title
        }
    }
}
```

> Form Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addArticle } from '../actions/index'

const Form = props => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState( '' ) // using react hooks

    const handleChange = e => {
        setTitle( e.target.value )
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        props.addArticle( { title } ) // this is where the action is dispatched
        setTitle( '' )
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
                type="text"
                id="title"
                value={ title }
                onChange={ handleChange }
            />
            <button>SAVE</button>
        </form>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addArticle: article => dispatch( addArticle( article ) ) // dispatching the action
    }
}

export default connect( null, mapDispatchToProps )( Form )
```

The expected result should be a new article title added to a basic list. I do have a seed of three article titles which work, but when I want to *add* an article title, it displays that error message mentioned above.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your state here was an object

```
const initialState = {
    articles: []
}
```

but here:

```
case ADD_ARTICLE:
            return [ ...state, action.article ] // Problem line
```

you are trying to spread an object into an array and also changing the state to an array). You shouldn't do this.

It's just the article that changes

I would change that to

```
case ADD_ARTICLE:
     return { ...state, 
         articles: [
             ...state.articles,
             action.article
         ] 
      }
```

Alternately,

since your `initialState` (object) only has one property `articles`, you could as well change it to

```
const initialState = []
```

This way, you can leave the rest of your reducer code. You would then have to change how you access the information from your reducer in your components

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your reducer:

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
    articles: []
}

export default ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case ADD_ARTICLE:
            const currentArticles = [...state.articles];
            currentArticles.push(action.article);
            return {
                ...state,
                articles: currentArticles
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't state gonna create problem with state = initialState and initialState being obj

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the initial state. you are trying to spread an object into an array. That is exactly what your error message says. You should change it to be

```js
import {
  ADD_ARTICLE
} from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  articles: []
}


//OBSERVE initialState.articles instead of initialState
export default (state = initialState.articles, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ARTICLE:
      return [...state, action.article] // Problem line
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```